# Redirecting to profile edit page after first login if account isn't complete in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

For my account and logging stuff I am using FOSUserBundle which fits all my requirements.

I have created registration form with only few inputs (username, email and password) for not scaring visitor with long registration forms. However for using newly created account, client needs to give informations about his company, address etc, so after first login I want to redirect my client to account edit page where he or she could fill all required inputs, but don't allow visit other account pages while profile aren't complete.

I have found good example how to redirect client after login, but this will work every time when client login, bet I need to do this only if client profile aren't complete.

Code to redirect user after login:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        form_login:
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /loggedinpage
```

Comment: So, you want your user to be unable to do anything unless he completed his profile?

Comment: Why not just put all the required fields in the registration form to being with?

Comment: Because I need a lot of information from client and a lot of clients just leave registration when sees so long forms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago I had a rather similar requirement. My solution was to use a request listener which checks a few preconditions and redirects appropriately.

---

*src/Acme/HelloBundle/EventListener/UserRedirectListener.php*

```
<?php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class UserRedirectListener
{
  /**
   * @var SecurityContext
   */
  private $securityContext;

  /**
   * @var Router $router
   */
  private $router;

  /**
   * @var ValidatorInterface $validator
   */
  private $validator;

  /**
   * @param SecurityContext    $securityContext
   * @param Router             $router
   * @param RecursiveValidator $validator
   */
  public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Router $router, ValidatorInterface $validator) {
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    $this->router          = $router;
    $this->validator       = $validator;
  }

  /**
   * @param GetResponseEvent $event
   */
  public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
      // don't do anything if it's not the master request
      return;
    }

    // get the user
    $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
      return;
    }

    // validate
    $errors = $this->validator->validate($user, null, array('email'));
    if (count($errors) === 0) {
      return;
    }

    // get current route
    $route = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');

    // filter allowed routes
    switch ($route) {
      case 'some_route':
      case 'some_other_route':
        return;
    }

    // redirect
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('target_route')));
  }
}
```

*service.xml*

```
<service id="user_redirect_listener" class="%user_redirect_listener.class%">
  <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
  <argument type="service" id="router" />
  <argument type="service" id="validator" />
  <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" />
</service>
```

*validation.yml*

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        email_activated:
           - 'True': { groups: [email] }
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer! I think this is what I need. I will try to implement this code in my project, then tell about the results.

Comment: This seems correct but here are my thoughts. The check is "hard-coded", maybe give an example by passing the `Validator` service instead? The `_route` parameter may or may not exist upon onKernelRequest (depending on the priority). Relying on this may lead to problems in different situations. An alternative would be to listen to onKernelController instead, then replace the controller by a simple closure returing the `RedirectResponse`

Comment: @Touki Good ideas! Thanks for that! I'll try to make an update later. Regarding the *hard-coded* part, I think it would also be good to inject the target route and/or allowed routes from some configuration parameter, tough at the time there simply was no need for this to be configurable.

Comment: I have added @Yoshi code example and it of course works, but I would like to see the `Validator` service.

Comment: @RydelHouse I updated the example to show how you could use the validator service with a specific validation-group.

Comment: @Touki When using the `kernel.controller` event, how would you check which controller is allowed and which is not? Specifically when using extra bundles, e.g. FOSJsRoutingBundle/FOSRestBundle.

Comment: @Yoshi I have `Undefined class RecursiveValidator`. How I can add this class?

Comment: @RydelHouse I think `RecursiveValidator` was added with 2.5. Either update or check which class the validator service is.

Comment: @Yoshi Yet, validator injection should depend on `ValidatorInterface` so any validator would work. For your question, you can't *"know"* which routes will be allowed to *"bypass"*, I'd add a parameter in routes `options` (like `noredirect = true`). For the FOSxBundle bundles, you can add this parameter by [overriding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html) route definitions and adding this `options` parameter. Then you can check in router which routes are allowed by doing `$route->hasOption('noredirect')`

Comment: @Touki I wanted to use the `ValidatorInterface`, though I think I read that it was deprecated. But it could be that I just looked at the wrong position. // Aside from that, thanks a lot for the *noredirect-idea*. I'll definitely try that out!

Comment: @Yoshi You're right, the [**`Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface`**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src%2FSymfony%2FComponent%2FValidator%2FValidatorInterface.php) is deprecated in favor of [**`Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface`**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src%2FSymfony%2FComponent%2FValidator%2FValidator%2FValidatorInterface.php) since 2.5. However, support for this first interface will only be dropped at version 3.0, and since 2.3 is still active, you can still rely on it (just mind adding a warning)

Comment: I don't see the point of validating user for each request. Wouldn't be better just to add a flag 'is_complete' and set it to true when the user complete the profile ? I would configure a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, check if the user has complete profile and save the result in session. Check for the session value in the listener.

Comment: @Hpatoio Example: what if the business logic changes? You now need mandatory phone number? Or worse *(my case)* you want a specific business rule for a set of properties? You just cycle around 100k records wasting dev time by updating that flag to these that don't match the rule?

Comment: @Touki after registration the user has 'not_complete' as profile state. Once he has completed the profile it change to 'complete' state. If your business rule change just set all user to 'not_complete' and the system will validate the user again on login.

Comment: You don't really need to check all request, so you should subscribe to `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` instead.

Comment: @Hpatoio I think there is a point to only listen for a specific authentication event for specific use cases. Though I think this one needs a wider controll. How else would you capture the user navigating away from the profile form?